# MySQL query with subquery containing IN is very slow

Tags: mysql

I am having this problem with my query being slow and I believe it is because of my `IN` statement in the query.

It looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM genes g, 
    (SELECT DISTINCT gene_symbol, score FROM page_genes, genes WHERE 
page_genes.page_id IN
    (SELECT page_id FROM findzebra2.page WHERE umls_concept_id ='c0007361')) AS t
WHERE g.gene_id = t.gene_symbol
```

I have heard of using a JOIN statement instead but could not figure out how to replace it.

**Tables:**

genes

[image: genes]

page_genes

[image: page_genes]

findzebra2.page

[image: findzebra2.page]

**Expected output**

It should be the same table as *genes* but with filtered data corresponding to the query.

Comment: please share your table structure and expected output

Comment: NOTE: MySQL performance drops when using subqueries/functions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i understood your question then your query shold be

`SELECT g.* FROM genes g JOIN page_genes p on g.gene_id = p.gene_symbol JOIN findzebra2 f ON p.page_id = f.page_id WHERE f.umls_concept_id = 'c0007361';`

Comment: This worked perfectly and increased the speed by a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
select g.*
from genes g
join page p on p.gene_symbol = g.gene_id and p.umls_concept_id = 'c0007361'
join page_genes pg on pg.page_id = g.gene_id
```

Comment: page doesnt not contain a column gene_symbol

Comment: Then you can adjust your columns as per demand. But you can get clue the joins and their linked columns.